# ubuntu subshell in windows displaying junk for 0-15 unicode characters

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was working on a python library called urwid when I noticed this issue. It does not happen in native ubuntu. I've boiled it down to the following:

When I run the following python3 program which prints the first 15 unicode characeters:

```python
for i in range(0, 16):
    print(i, chr(i))
```

the windows ubuntu subshell prints junk characters, but the native ubuntu machine does not. I am trying to make the windows subshell NOT print these junk characters. Is there any way to do that? I tried downloading and installing source code pro and ubuntu mono fonts in the windows subshell but that just changed which junk character was printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is affected by your terminal emulator.  What you're printing in these cases is a set of control characters, some of which are printable, but most of which are not.  In general, it's not a good idea to send such characters to the screen unless you are interested in their effects on the terminal, and if you don't want them to be rendered on the screen, you should avoid printing them.

In all likelihood, the difference is that the native Ubuntu terminal emulator (probably GNOME Terminal) doesn't print these characters to the screen, while Windows Terminal does.  Both are valid and correct responses.  So you'd need to switch to a different terminal emulator that doesn't have this behavior if you don't want to see them and don't want to change your code.